# Hive SMB join versus SMB map join

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

From this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization#LanguageManualJoinOptimization-ProsandConsofClient-SideHashTables) i see that that SMB has a map join flavor. From my understanding, SMB itself performs the merge on the map side by loading the buckets from the join tables. How different is the SMB map join from this?